# How to query insert postgresql in servlet

Tags: java, postgresql, servlets

I need help for my problem about query  insert postgresql in servlet and i have a query like this

```
public void doInsert(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {  
String msisdn = "";
String prog_id = "";
String branch = "";

res.setContentType("text/html");  
String result = null; 
msisdn      =req.getParameter("msisdn");
prog_id     =req.getParameter("prog_id");  
branch      =req.getParameter("branch");  

try{  

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase","username","password");   

        ps=con.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO reg_agent(msisdn, prog_id, branch) VALUES(?, ?, ?");   

        ps.setString(1, msisdn);
        ps.setString(2, prog_id);
        ps.setString(3, branch);
        int i=ps.executeUpdate(); 

   }

}
catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("record not found "+ex.getMessage());

}
}
```

But, the query can't insert to my database in postgresql.
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you see any exception there ?

Comment: there no have an error, but data can't get into database @zillani

Comment: Double check that this method is actually called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to log the request params and see if you are getting the requested values in your servlet,

```
public void doInsert(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {  
String msisdn = "";
String prog_id = "";
String branch = "";

res.setContentType("text/html");  
String result = null; 
msisdn      =req.getParameter("msisdn");
prog_id     =req.getParameter("prog_id");  
branch      =req.getParameter("branch");  

System.out.println("MSISDN: "+msisdn);
System.out.println("PRGID: "+prog_id);
System.out.println("BRANCH: "+branch);   

try{  

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase","username","password");   

        ps=con.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO reg_agent(msisdn, prog_id, branch) VALUES(?, ?, ?");   

        ps.setString(1, msisdn);
        ps.setString(2, prog_id);
        ps.setString(3, branch);
        int i=ps.executeUpdate(); 

   }

}
catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("record not found "+ex.getMessage());

}
}
```

Comment: if you don't see the logs, then you need to make sure that the servlet is actually called. let me know if that helped @Philipus Silaen